# Abstract Views for API level

Tags: java, android, layout, abstract-class

So currently I have a view

```
            <TextureView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/texture_view"
                android:visibility="gone" />
```

Which only supports Android API 14 and up ... I want to create a different view for API < 14 ... So I want create an abstract view and call it in the XML layout file

```
            <CustomView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/texture_view"
                android:visibility="gone" />
```

Is it possible in code to do the following

```
CustomView v;

if (DeviceVersion.atLeast(API_14)) {
       v = (TextureView) root.findViewById(R.id.texture_view);
 }
 else {
      v = (SurfaceView) root.findViewById(R.id.texture_view);
 }
```

Where CustomView is part of both Surface and Texture ... or Do i need to make two different View say CustomSurface and CustomTexture that implement CustomView ?

If there is a better way to get around this API view issue, please let me know also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource system provides you with a way to do this:

1. Create a layout file `my_render_view.xml` that contains only the `SurfaceView` and put it in `res/layout`.
2. Create a 2nd layout file `my_render_view.xml` that contains only the `TextureView` and put it in `res/layout-v14`.
3. In the layout file that should contain `SurfaceView` or `TextureView` you can add a `<include layout="@layout/my_render_view />`.

The resource system will load the respective layout file based on the API version. `TextureView` for API version 14 and newer, otherwise `SurfaceView`.

In your code you probably need to provide 2 code paths, similar to what you have in your questions:

```
if (DeviceVersion.atLeast(API_14)) {
    TextureView view = (TextureView) root.findViewById(R.id.texture_view);
    // ... do something with TextureView ...
}
else {
    SurfaceView view = (SurfaceView) root.findViewById(R.id.texture_view);
    // .... do something with SurfaceView
}
```

Or hide the code paths in a container class:

```
abstract class RenderView {

    public abstract void doSomething();
}

class DefaultRenderView {

    private SurfaceView mView;

    public DefaultRenderView(SurfaceView view) {
        mView = view;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        // SurfaceView specific code
    }
}

class TextureRenderView {

    private TextureView mView;

    public TextureRenderView(TextureView view) {
        mView = view;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        // TextureView specific code
    }
}

RenderView renderView;

if (DeviceVersion.atLeast(API_14)) {
    renderView = new TextureRenderView(
        (TextureView) root.findViewById(R.id.texture_view));
}
else {
    renderView = new DefaultRenderView(
        (SurfaceView) root.findViewById(R.id.texture_view));
}
```

The Android Developer Documentation provides some more information about the include element [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Comment: So for API >14 devices will it check v14 first and if its not there it will check the normal layout folder? ... or do i have to move everything in layout-v14

Comment: For any resource it will fall back to the less specific resource definition. So yes, if something does not exist in "layout-v14", it will try to pick it up from "layout". The exact algorithm how resources are looked up is described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Comment: Thats awesome, One more thing in code how would I access this abstract View ? and will the view given be Surface or Texture or will the system determine that for us